# Do you guys know why my Y rotation won't change?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to make a fps shooter in unity c#, but what ever function i use to change my Y rotation, won't move.
The first time i tested it it worked, but then an hour later after working with some other stuff that has nothing to do with this script, it all of a sudden didn't. I have tried .Rotate(), localRotation, Quaternion.Eulern anything but it doesn't move. I have also checked to see if it was because the variable i was using wasn't set, but it was.

Please help if you can!

```
float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    
    xRotation -= mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f,90f);
    
    //x
    Debug.Log(mouseX);
    player.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,mouseX,0);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,mouseX,0);
    
    //y
    
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation,0,0);
```

Comment: The top line isnt actually pushed back...

Answer (score 0):

xRotation -= mouseY; You are subtracting mouse Y rotation from mouse X rotation, X and Y are different axis! Please look up tutorials on rotation, like:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/288948/rotate-around-local-y-axis.html

Comment: MouseY is the mouses Y 2d pos. XRotation is the rotation around the X axis. Plus its the mousex that doesn't seem to work.